# CSS vertical writing error with spacing

Tags: html, css

I am trying to change the written text from horizontal to vertical, applying 
CSS

```
 h4{
    font-family: sans-serif;
    margin-top: 280px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
       }
```

And i obtain this:

[image]

So the problem is that "Milesti Mici" the blue div is 2 words separated by space, and it outputs the second word from the new line, but I need in the same line. I think here is a kind of default property.

Thank you for your time!
Here is the html code

```
<div id="unu">  <h4>Albina</h4>         </div>

<div id="doi">  <h4>Catedrala</h4>  </div>

<div id="trei"> <h4>Milesti Mici</h4>   </div>
```

Comment: Add width: 100% to your h4.

Comment: Please, add the rest of your CSS code as well. If not we can not know the real reason.

Answer (score 2):

Try with this property:

```
h4 {
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```